# Creating a salt in python

Tags: python, salt, base62

How would I create a random, 16-character base-62 salt in python? I need it for a protocol and I'm not sure where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> ALPHABET = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
>>> chars=[]
>>> for i in range(16):
    chars.append(random.choice(ALPHABET))

>>> "".join(chars)
'wE9mg9pu2KSmp5lh'
```

This should work.

Comment: Nice answer, but the last 4 lines can be done more idiomatically with just `''.join(random.choice(ALPHABET) for i in range(16))`

Comment: @ScottGriffiths I wouldn't say that it is more idiomatic because it is a one liner...  It is a nice one line though, so awesome :)

Comment: How about `''.join(chr(random.randint(32,126)) for i in range(16))`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, not base62.

Comment: Also consider creating the alphabet with: `string.ascii_letters + string.digits`

Comment: Also see secrets.choice (in 3.6+) for a cryptographically secure version, replacing random.choice in the example.

Comment: This comment is outdated, are we able to change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 35):

You shouldn't use UUIDs, they are unique, not random: [Is using a CreateUUID() function as salt a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3596598/1224926)

Your salts should use a cryptographically secure random numbers, in python 2.4+, os.urandom is the source of these (if you have a good timing source).

```
# for some given b62encode function

salt = b62encode(os.urandom(16))
```

you could also use a generator from [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/) or other awesome crypto/hashing library that is well known and vetted by the people much more expert than I am.

```
import bcrypt
salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
# will be 29 chars you can then encode it however you want.
```

Comment: It gives me an error:

ImportError: No module named bcrypt

Comment: pip install bcrypt should remove the error... show that the bcrypt package is not installed in your computer ---  anurageldorado

Comment: Your base_64 example does not work. A hash may contain `[./a-zA-Z0-9]`, yours will additionally contain `+`, `=` and `\n`.

Comment: @cdauth given that I misread the question to begin with (base 62 was asked for), I've since updated this to reflect this.  I assume that their exists an encoding function though - easy enough to find one of those on SO.

Answer (score 25):

Old question, new solution with [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

```
import secrets

random_string = secrets.token_hex(8)
```

Will produce a cryptographically strong 16-character random string.

Use this over standard pseudo-random number generators as they are much less secure.

To quote from the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) page:

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

Answer (score 11):

These days there is an official `mksalt` method in the `crypt` module.
It does not give you a simple 16 char long string but adds `$digit$` in front required by most hashing functions anyway. If you are hashing passwords this is probably much safer to use.

```
import crypt
crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)
```

Generates outputs like the following:

```
$6$wpg9lx1sVFNFSCrP
```

Comment: Not present in python 2.7

Comment: Updating an old answer, these days the `crypt` module is deprecated since Python version 3.11, and will be removed in version 3.13 (see [PEP594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#crypt))

Answer (score 0):

in base64:

```
import random, base64, struct
rand_float = random.SystemRandom().random()
salt = base64.b64encode((struct.pack('!d', rand_float)))
```

this will be 12 chars

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string

def get_salt(size=16, chars=None):
    if not chars:
        chars = ''.join(
            [string.ascii_uppercase, 
             string.ascii_lowercase, 
             string.digits]
        )
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on the salting principal of "salts should be unique, not random"?

Comment: @T.Woody - According to what I know, Salt and secret are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use 'secrets' module to generate secure randomness https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html
it specifically crafted for this kind of jobs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34545468)

Answer (score -2):

I kind of like:

```
import md5, uuid
m = md5.md5()
m.update(uuid.uuid4())
print m.digest()[:16]
```

That will be very, very random.

Comment: Did you mean `m.update(str(uuid.uuid4()))`? And also `m.hexdigest()[:16]`? But still, that wouldn't be in `base62` right?

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the code.  I figure since my solution uses a subset of the base62 characters it might work for the original poster.